# Apache error when setting up Silex Bootstrap: unable to check htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set up a website using Silex Bootstrap.
I've put it in my folder with other web projects and changed the DocumentRoot in the Apache config.

```
<Directory /folder/to/silex_projects/web>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
```

But I can't open the index page of the framework, Apache gives:

> [Mon Dec 17 21:10:52 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /folder/to/silex_project/web/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I've chmod'ed the whole project folder with `chmod a+r -R`. Other projects in the same folder are working fine with the `.htaccess` file.

The `.htaccess` file does exist.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`chmod 755 -R /silex_project/` solved my problem. I still don't know why Apache needs write permissions to work.

Comment: this does solve the problem, but does not explain it, see user1428022's anwser

Comment: Just `chmod 755 .` worked for me so problem was with permission for project folder

Answer (score 19):

This is probably because the user running Apache doesn't have eXecute permission on the directory. It is also needed to read the files within it. `chmod a+rx /folder/to/silex_projects` would probably have solved your error.

Your `chmod 755 -R` doesn't solve this by also giving write access, but because this just happens to add the eXecute also.

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks. @OrangeTux Apache does not need write permission to work.

Comment: I also had to add execution permission to the **parent** folder like `chmod +x /home/myuser`. The issue appeared when I moved the site from `/var/www/html` to `/home/myuser/html`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers posted, something else than can bite you in this situation is SELinux (if it's enabled) if you're changing up anything where files might be accessed from the distributions "default" locations.

The fix is to add an appropriate policy to selinux for the directory/files, or disable it if you do not want selinux security running.

Answer (score 1):

i have this error too and find this good refrence  [(13)Permission denied: /home/username/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=363)

When viewing your domain, if you see the error "Forbidden" and then check your apache logs:
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/var/log/httpd/domains/domain.com.error.log

and see the error:

```
[crit] [client 1.2.3.4] (13)Permission denied: /home/username/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

it would imply that apache does not have read access on your /home/username directory.

The cause for this can be permission related, config related or ownership related.

Apache runs as user "apache", thus the directory must be +x for that user or group.

1) As of DirectAdmin 1.38.0, we implement the secure_acccess_group feature, which will set the /home/user (for Users) to chmod 750 and chown username:access.   The apache user will be in the "access" group.  To confirm this, type the following:

```
[root@server]# grep ^access: /etc/group
access:x:506:apache,nobody,mail,majordomo,daemon
```

and you should get something similar to the output shown.

If you get a blank list of Users, then the access group exists, but is empty.   To correctly fill the group (on RedHat/CentOS/Debian systems), type:

```
usermod -G access apache
usermod -G access nobody
usermod -G access mail
usermod -G access majordomo
usermod -G access daemon
```

on FreeBSD systems, the command to create the group is:

```
pw groupadd -n access -M apache,nobody,mail,majordomo,daemon
```

but this implies the group doesn't yet exist.  This case has not been seen on FreeBSD, so likely won't be needed.

Comment: Adding +X to my symlinked folder solved for me. (~/public_html is symlinked to ~/builds/build_UNIX/public_html I had to +X the build public_html folder)