# Apache: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable - Read/Execture set right

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My web server is giving Permission 403 Forbidden errors and checking the error_log

[Sun Aug 24 13:06:49 2014] [crit] [client 162.205.68.223] (13)Permission denied: /home/www/www.networkcmo.com/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

I have done the following:

1. Changed /home (recursive) to chmod 755
2. Made sure the .htaccess file exists and is not corrupt (I can 'cat' it from the shell)
3. Changed the owner of .htaccess to be 'apache'

None of these fix the issue.

I have looked at these other SO posts:
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607300/htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htaccess-file-ensure-it-is-readable-and) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627084/permission-denied-var-www-abc-htaccess-pcfg-openfile-unable-to-check-htacces) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921529/apache-error-when-setting-up-silex-bootstrap-unable-to-check-htaccess-file) and they basically all talk about read+execute or ownership which I have tried.

The permissions right now for /home/www are

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 6 ftp webusers 4096 Aug  2 14:46 www
```

The permissions for /home/www/www.networkcmo.com/www are

```
drwxr-xr-x. 4 ftp    webusers 4096 Aug 20 06:50 www
```

The file permissions for .htaccess is

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   1594 Aug 20 05:59 .htaccess
```

The one thing that stands out is the '+' sign at the end of the home/www which indicates some special folder permission things in that folder/files but I dont know if that will effect this.

The apache user is a part of the webusers group

Comment: I had the same problem what I did was to recreate the .htacces set ownship/permissions etc and restarted the apache, and for some reason it worked for me !!

Answer (score 7):

I've done chmod 755 -R /home/username/public_html and it worked for me.

Comment: I was working with Apache2 `password digest files` and did not use `.htaccess` files to handle authorization. So the mentioned error in the Apache2 log files of the question was totally misleading, because i did not have any `.htaccess` file. Doing what this answer said solved my problem.